# Printing values

Tags: java, arrays

I am posting this question related to how to write values one below the other without using `System.out.println()`. I believe generally when we want to print out values we can use arrays or lists etc. It would go something like this, for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[] myList = new int[10] ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++){
            myList[i] = i ;
            System.out.println(myList[i] + "\n"); 
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to know how to print values in a box like this:

```
1  2   3    4 

5  6   7    8
```

Thank you,

Comment: You can use `System.out.print(...)` which won't terminate the line by itself. Please elaborate more what exactly you need as well as how the desired output of your code snippet should (exactly) look like.

Comment: oh yes what i mean is how i can do this with just using system libraries where i dont need to include array libraries and using arrays to make it as i was thinking maybe there is a much faster way to display characters on the screen which might be more effective in a complex project

Comment: You don't need arrays to print numbers next to or under each other. Please elaborate more on what you actually want to achieve – it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you want to achieve. If your purpose is to display data on standard out (console) I don't see any reason not to use System.out.println(), .print() or .printf().

*Warning, long answer with questionable relevance*

To print your values in two rows can be done in many different ways. Here is one option:

```
private static void printNums2() {
    int rowLength = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + ((i % rowLength == 0) ? " \n" : " "));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints the current number, i, and then checks if i has reached the end of a row with modulus. If so, prints a new line character. (Loop starts at 1 and goes to 8 to match the numbers in your output.)

I noticed in your example output there are varying number of spaces as well. Here is a version of the above which achieves this as well:

```
private static void printNums2b() {
    int rowLength = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-" + (i % rowLength + 2) + "d" + ((i % rowLength == 0) ? " \n" : ""), i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

In short, it uses printf() to format the output and sets the padding on the number to modulus of the position (to account for rows) + 1 (because 0 doesn't work).

One interpretation of your question is that you don't want to print too often. There is no reason we have to print every number by itself. We can accumulate the output and then print it all at once.

Here is a solution using a StringBuilder (standard Java, no extra libraries needed):

```
private static void printNums3() {
    int rowLength = 4;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        sb.append(i).append(' ');
        if ((i % rowLength == 0)) {
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Puts all the numbers in the StringBuilder, adds a newline at the end after every 4th number and then prints the entire thing at the end.

And again, with varying spaces:

```
private static void printNums3b() {
    int rowLength = 4;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%-" + (i % rowLength + 2) + "d", i));
        if ((i % rowLength == 0)) {
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I don't think there is any particular benefit to using arrays. But then again, there are many ways to achieve this output. Since we don't know more about what you really want to achieve, if your array serves some other purpose (I removed the array because it's not needed for the printing) or what type of data you want to print other than numbers, I can't really give more ideas.

Comment: string builder ,  I wasn't much aware of it (  still practicing new concepts )  that solves my issue with repeatedly having to print out values using  system.out.println(); but string builder solves the issue itself thanks